# Problem configuration with roscore?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I recently install Ros Kinetic, using the tutorials, but I've seen some troubles while I launch the roscore, because it only launch when I have internet connection.

```
:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/luigi/.ros/log/8a34264e-89af-11e7-b0b2-3bf20ac5beb2/roslaunch-ubuntu-4007.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Unable to contact my own server at [http://ubuntu:36413/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check
for errors by running:

    ping ubuntu

For more tips, please see

    http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

**But ,when I get internet conection, there's no problem

```
:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/luigi/.ros/log/5375e854-89af-11e7-b0b2-3bf20ac5beb2/roslaunch-ubuntu-3860.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:39853/
ros_comm version 1.12.7


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3871]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ubuntu:11311/

setting /run_id to 5375e854-89af-11e7-b0b2-3bf20ac5beb2
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3884]
started core service [/rosout]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269605/problem-configuration-with-roscore?/) by [Luis_Valdez](https://answers.ros.org/users/31703/luis_valdez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-25**:
What is the output from `printenv | grep ROS`? Also, what do you mean by internet connection? Do you mean WiFi or a wired connection?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-25**:
I edited your question to make it more readable. Using the Preformat Text (`101010`) button on terminal output and source code makes questions much easier to read and answer.

**Comment by [Luis_Valdez](https://answers.ros.org/users/31703/luis_valdez/) on 2017-08-26**:
:~$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/luigi/RoboticsCourses/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/luigi/RoboticsCourses/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic

**Comment by [Luis_Valdez](https://answers.ros.org/users/31703/luis_valdez/) on 2017-08-26**:
thanks, I mean wifi connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your hostname is `ubuntu`, and when your PC doesn't have a network connection configured, it can't ping itself (or create loopback connections to itself). This is probably because (1) there is no loopback network adapter or (2) there is no host entry to identify `ubuntu` as the local IP address. Try these steps:

1. Ensure that you have the loopback network adapter set up. In a terminal, run `ifconfig`, which will print information about all of your network adapters. Make sure there is an entry for `lo`. It should look something like this:

   ```
    lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:76611664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76611664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:4619547412 (4.6 GB)  TX bytes:4619547412 (4.6 GB)
   ```

   If you don't see an entry for `lo`, edit `/etc/network/interfaces` (you'll need to use `sudo`) and add these lines to configure the loopback adapter:

   ```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
   ```

   Then, save the file and restart your computer.
2. If step 1 doesn' fix the problem, it might be that your computer isn't finding an IP address for its own hostname. Make sure that `/etc/hosts` includes a line like this:

   ```
     127.0.1.1  ubuntu
   ```

   If it isn't there, add it. (You'll need to use `sudo` to edit this file as well.)

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis_Valdez](https://answers.ros.org/users/31703/luis_valdez/) on 2017-08-26**:
Thanks Ed !!! Apparently the name of my computer in the hosts file was incorrect, I fixed it and it seems that the roscore works well even without wifi connection
Thank you!!